# Electron. Как понять какой файл открыт программой?

Tags: electron

Делаю программку на основе Electron. Инсталлятор, всё такое.
В винде привязываю открывать файлы определённого типа с помощью этой программы.

Пример. Файл 0001.buff дабл клик - открывается моя программа на базе Electron
Но как это обработать изнутри ?
Вероятно есть аргументы или переменная. Но никак не могу найти что то похожее в документации. Ааааа!!! спасите, помогите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Проверьте `process.argv`

Comment: @D-side : process.argv: Array[15]

0: "C:\viv\VIV-win32-ia32\VIV.exe"

1: "--type=renderer"

2: "--no-sandbox"
3: "--enable-deferred-image-decoding"
4: "--lang=ru"
5: "--app-user-model-id=electron.app.image-viewer"
6: "--node-integration=true"
7: "--device-scale-factor=1"
8: "--enable-pinch-virtual-viewport"
9: "--enable-delegated-renderer"
10: "--num-raster-threads=2"
11: "--gpu-rasterization-msaa-sample-count=8"
12: "--use-image-texture-target=3553"
13: "--channel=9140.2.2015347327\484741393"
14: "/prefetch:673131151"
length: 15

Насколько я вижу тут нет ничего полезного в данном вопросе

Comment: Был не прав. Если из main.js обратиться к process.argv то можно получить то что надо. D-side cпасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ОС типично "открывает файл в программе", передавая путь к файлу первым "параметром командной строки". Примерно так:

```
program "C:\texts\text.txt"
```

Где и как их получить, зависит от среды исполнения. Всё совсем просто в C, там функция `main` (точка входа) получает этот массив прямо в аргументах. В NodeJS они же выведены в `process.argv`.

Но есть нюанс. Electron работает внутри процесса Chromium'а, и этот процесс получает целый ворох параметров, связанных с внутренней кухней Electron. Именно эти параметры видны, если посмотреть в `process.argv` в **загрузчике**. В самом приложении там будет то, что ожидается.